# Bootstrap container 100%

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently converting our existing shop to run bootstrap.

On the product pages we have a section of images / icons. They are laid out as with the following css

```
.ts-2 {
   text-align: left;
   width: 318px;
}

.ts-2-2 {
   float: left;
   margin-top: 2px;
   padding: 2px;
   width: 70px;
   text-align:center;
}

.gen-2 {
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
font-size:10px;
}
```

Which works fine on our current site. but I want to put these inside a responsive container with 100% width in the new site.

at the moment that's not happening

You can see what I mean here.

https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/store_v8/shopexd.asp?id=848

Comment: This doesn't look like `Bootstrap` markup.  Please create a fiddle with https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/ including HTML and CSS and let us know what is working and not working.  You can learn more about `Bootstrap` at http://getbootstrap.com/.

Comment: Hi, no it's not bootstrap markup, this is the original css to display the image icons, what I need to do is replace this or wrap it to make it fit in the new design which I linked too.

Comment: So, are you going to share the code you have written using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of layout do you want to achieve here, but I guess you want to have a parallel row that takes the whole line when there's enough horizontal dimension, simply put, `width:100%` element that has a full of items in itself.

**First thing to do**

is to decide how many items should be displayed on a single row. You need to refer to [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Let's assume that you decided to display 12 items in a row horizontally and make it responsive. And then you may tweak your code like below.

---

**Warning**

As I commented below on `CSS` code section, `col-md-1` is a predefined CSS class of Bootstrap. So ***make sure that you don't have this kind of custom CSS below for Bootstrap element***. It could seriously harm Bootstrap's responsive feature.

---

Hope this will help you or at least give you some ideas to achieve what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#shrink').click(function(e) {
      $('#virtualBody').css('width', '70%');
  });
  
  $('#expand').click(function(e) {
      $('#virtualBody').css('width','100%');
  });
})
```

```css
/* normally you don't need to define below css stub
*  because bootstrap already has this property according to your screen or device sizes.
*  Somehow linking the css doesn't work properly.
*  So I added this col-md-1 here.
*/
.col-md-1 {
  width:8.33333333%;
  float:left;
}
/* col-md-1 custom css ended */





.ts-2-2 {
  text-align:center;
}

/*  */
.ts-2-2 img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
}

.gen-2 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="virtualBody">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="ts-2-2">
   <p class="gen-2">
        Category<br/>
    <img border="0" src="https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/images/icons/safety_8.gif" alt="Category 2 :: 8 Metres" title="Category 2 :: 8 Metres">
  8 Metres
      </p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="ts-2-2">
   <p class="gen-2">
        Category<br/>
    <img border="0" src="https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/images/icons/safety_8.gif" alt="Category 2 :: 8 Metres" title="Category 2 :: 8 Metres">
  8 Metres
      </p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="ts-2-2">
   <p class="gen-2">
        Category<br/>
    <img border="0" src="https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/images/icons/safety_8.gif" alt="Category 2 :: 8 Metres" title="Category 2 :: 8 Metres">
  8 Metres
      </p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="ts-2-2">
   <p class="gen-2">
        Category<br/>
    <img border="0" src="https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/images/icons/safety_8.gif" alt="Category 2 :: 8 Metres" title="Category 2 :: 8 Metres">
  8 Metres
      </p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="ts-2-2">
   <p class="gen-2">
        Category<br/>
    <img border="0" src="https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/images/icons/safety_8.gif" alt="Category 2 :: 8 Metres" title="Category 2 :: 8 Metres">
  8 Metres
      </p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="ts-2-2">
   <p class="gen-2">
        Category<br/>
    <img border="0" src="https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/images/icons/safety_8.gif" alt="Category 2 :: 8 Metres" title="Category 2 :: 8 Metres">
  8 Metres
      </p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="ts-2-2">
   <p class="gen-2">
        Category<br/>
    <img border="0" src="https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/images/icons/safety_8.gif" alt="Category 2 :: 8 Metres" title="Category 2 :: 8 Metres">
  8 Metres
      </p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="ts-2-2">
   <p class="gen-2">
        Category<br/>
    <img border="0" src="https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/images/icons/safety_8.gif" alt="Category 2 :: 8 Metres" title="Category 2 :: 8 Metres">
  8 Metres
      </p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="ts-2-2">
   <p class="gen-2">
        Category<br/>
    <img border="0" src="https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/images/icons/safety_8.gif" alt="Category 2 :: 8 Metres" title="Category 2 :: 8 Metres">
  8 Metres
      </p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="ts-2-2">
   <p class="gen-2">
        Category<br/>
    <img border="0" src="https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/images/icons/safety_8.gif" alt="Category 2 :: 8 Metres" title="Category 2 :: 8 Metres">
  8 Metres
      </p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="ts-2-2">
   <p class="gen-2">
        Category<br/>
    <img border="0" src="https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/images/icons/safety_8.gif" alt="Category 2 :: 8 Metres" title="Category 2 :: 8 Metres">
  8 Metres
      </p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="ts-2-2">
   <p class="gen-2">
        Category<br/>
    <img border="0" src="https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/images/icons/safety_8.gif" alt="Category 2 :: 8 Metres" title="Category 2 :: 8 Metres">
  8 Metres
      </p>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>

</div>

<h3>See shrink and expand</h3>

<button id="shrink">shrink</button>
<button id="expand">expand</button>
```

Comment: That worked a treat!

Just need to try a few other things, but thank you very much for your help in this.